# Update MySQL database Symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have a MySQL database and frontend DataTables view and work with Symfony.

I have 2 buttons on my tables. Delete and edit. 
If I click on delete, it deletes the row from the DataTables and from MySqL. Works with this code:

```
  /**
   * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="deletepage")
   * @Template()
   */
  public function delete($id)
  {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $events = $em -> getRepository('AppBundle:eqAli')->find($id);
      $em -> remove($events);
      $em -> flush();

      return $this->redirectToroute('homepage');
  }
```

I have an edit button, which redirects to an edit page, where the data from that row is auto-filled.
What I am trying to achieve is that once there is made a change by a user on that page and the user clicks on save, that the new information will be updated into MySQL. So no delete, but update.

I am trying to achieve that with this code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit/update/{id}", name="updatepage")
 * @Template()
 */
public function update($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $events = $em -> getRepository('AppBundle:eqAli')->find($id);
    $em -> persist($events);
    $em -> flush();

    return $this->redirectToroute('homepage');
}
```

But that does nothing. It does get the right ID, I can click, just no update into MySQL. The path etc is right because when I change persist into delete, the button works.

Anyone a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are fetching single `eqAli` entity, ordering Entity Manager to manage it and flush all changes to your entities into database.

The problem is that you are not making actual changes to your entity before saving.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But how can I resolve that?

Comment: You should make changes to the Entity. Now you just fetch one `$events = $em -> getRepository('AppBundle:eqAli')->find($id);` and persist it right away `$em -> persist($events); $em -> flush();` so it is logical that there are no updates in the db. What do you want to do to the Entity??

Comment: What I want to achieve is that the changes are made into the MySQL as well after saving.

Comment: @Robbert you can, for example, do something like `$events->updateWithSomeData($data);` before flushing. You can get this `$data` from request body or your database.

Comment: But then where declare the function updateWithSomeData? And what has to be done in that function?

Comment: @Robbert this is an example of function that is inside your Entity(Model). It does whatever transformations you want to make with your entity.
So it is actual updating that you want to be flushed into database later.

Answer (score 0):

Ehhh ...

All should be in editAction (no redirect to update route necessary) , below you have  working example, try to implement it on your case (it's a little bit more  advanced , but you should catch idea ) .

```

```
 /**
 * @ParamConverter(name="reklama", class="SomeBundle:Reklamy")
 * @Template()
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Reklamy $reklama
 */
public function editAction(Request $request,Reklamy $reklama){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form=$this->createForm(new ReklamyType(),$reklama);
    if($request->getMethod()=="POST"){
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isValid()){
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('someroute')
        }
    }
    return array('form'=>$form->createView());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What is your Request and Reklamy in your @param? Entities?

Comment: Reklamy  is my entity and request is standart sf class  Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something with the `$events` entity that you found, like so:

```
$events = $em -> getRepository('AppBundle:eqAli')->find($id);
...
$events->modifyDate( new DateTime() );
...
$em -> persist($events);
$em -> flush();
```

Where for example `modifyDate` is a method that is part of the `eqAli` Entity. I show `...` before and after to indicate you might need to do other changes to your entity. In your original code, you are not changing anything at all. That's why you don't see any differences in the database.